# Copy object to another scene, but keep data

Tags: objects, linked-data, scene

What I need is to make a copy of an object to another scene, but keep the object data the same (link).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 ways. Create a new scene, then...

**2.9 update:**

Select your object on the original scene, go in the *Object* menu *Link / Transfer Data > Link Objects to Scene*, then Choose your new scene.

2.7:

Select your object on the original scene, go in the *Object* menu > *Make Links* > *Objects to Scene* > then choose your new scene.

[image]

You could also create an object in the new scene, select it and go in the *Properties* panel > *Data*, and in the top dropdown menu (*Browse Mesh Data to be Linked*) choose the mesh you want.

[image]

To make an object independent, click on the 2 that will appear next to the data name.